# Getting 500 Internal server error from application deployed on IHS and WAS server

Tags: sockets, stream, websphere-8, ibmhttpserver

Web based application intermittently throwing '500 Internal Server Error'. This application is deployed on WAS 8.0 server with IHS and WAS servers hosted on different machines. Please find below the TRACE level plugin logs at IHS end.

```
DEBUG: ws_common: websphereExecute: Wrote the request; reading the response (timeout 900) 
DETAIL: lib_htresponse: htresponseRead: Reading the response: 64040a70 TRACE: lib_rio: Blocking for read, waiting 900 
DEBUG: lib_rio.c line 896 : Read failed, rc=104 
DEBUG: lib_htresponse: htresponseSetError: Setting the error to: |READ_FAILED|(1, Line: 713) 
DEBUG: ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to read from an old stream; probably Keep-Alive timeout fired 
DEBUG: ws_transport: transportStreamDequeue: Checking for existing stream from the queue 
DEBUG: lib_stream: destroyStream: Destroying the stream 
DEBUG: lib_rio: rclose: socket 13 closed 
STATS: ws_server: serverSetFailoverStatus: Server xxxxx : pendingRequests 0 failedRequests 7 affinityRequests 57 totalRequests 51. 
ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to execute the transaction to 'xxxxx' on host 'yyyyy'; will try another one 
ERROR: ws_common: websphereWriteRequestReadResponse: Failed to find an app server to handle this request 
ERROR: ESI: getResponse: failed to get response: rc = 10 DEBUG: ESI: esiHandleRequest: failed to get response 
DEBUG: ESI: esiRequestUrlStackDestroy 
DEBUG: ESI: cacheURL: '/site/index' 
DETAIL: ESI: esiRequestPopUrl: '/site/index' 
DEBUG: ESI: esiUrlDestroy: '/site/index' 
ERROR: [://site/index] ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request rc=10 
DEBUG: ws_common: websphereCloseConnection 
DETAIL: ws_common: websphereEndRequest: Ending the request
```

Please help me to get the issue resolved. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look in the SystemOut.log on WebSphere what is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

rc=104 is the linux return code indicating that the socket was reset by the partner address so you need to look at the application server for errors.

Comment: I checked but there is not log generated at WAS end during the request timestamp. Can you please let me know the cause of the below error? Is it a network/firewall related or WAS/IHS related error?

"Failed to read from an old stream; probably Keep-Alive timeout fired"

Comment: "Failed to read from an old stream; probably Keep-Alive timeout fired" means plugin received a notification on the socket but no data was available.  "Read failed, rc=104" is an OS return code, ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer. I would suggest examining a network trace of the connection to see who is resetting the connection. If it is not the application server, it may be a firewall or some other device in between the endpoints.